# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffi'

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

After building success heroku **git push heroku main**.when I executed that **gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app** i get this error.I searched in google but didnot found answer.With procfile data as  **web: gunicorn tictactoe.wsgi** .tictactoe my project name.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\anves\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\gunicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import fcntl
  File "c:\users\anves\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fcntl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ffi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffi'
```

Answer (score 0):

There could possibly be 2 cases:

1. You have not activated the virtualenv
2. The package is not installed

Comment: I have installed many package suggested in web like micropython-ffilib.I would be happy if u Guide me

Comment: Thank u for ur response I am able to deploy and get my project online without application error on heroku.I think the prolem was due to the virtual env.Thank u.